# R hclust: common order for multiple trees

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I am making trees using hclust. I have several distances defined on a common set. I want to find, as close to possible, a common order of the set for each distance without any crossing edges in the plot. For example, I would like to have the 1 through 5 leaves on the left side for both trees in this example.

```
x<-seq(1,10)
y<-c(1.3,2.4,3.6,4.9,5.2,6.9,7.9,8.7,9.6,10.1)
X<-hclust(dist(x))
Y<-hclust(dist(y))
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(X)
plot(Y)
```

In general, is there an algorithm to find this order, if one exists? Or, at least find one order for each distance that is close to the others? I understand this can be done with dendrograms using order or sort, but I think those trees are less informative.

[Plots as hclust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a2Ww.png)

[Plots as dendrograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3OR6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sort` function from the `dendextend` library:

```
library(dendextend)

x<-seq(1,10)
y<-c(1.3,2.4,3.6,4.9,5.2,6.9,7.9,8.7,9.6,10.1)
X<-hclust(dist(x)) %>% as.dendrogram %>% sort %>% as.hclust
Y<-hclust(dist(y)) %>% as.dendrogram %>% sort %>% as.hclust
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot( X )
plot( Y )
```

The function simply tries to sort the plot by the index of each leaf.

Comment: I would like to keep it as an hclust class instead of dendrogram. The plot function for hclust makes it a lot easier to read the heights and visually understand the branches. I don't find the dendrogram plots to be as nice. I updated the post to clarify why.

Comment: @FScott You can convert back and forth between hclust and dendrogram.  I don't think you'd lose information doing so, see the updated answer.

Comment: You can use the hang.dendrogram function to have the dendrogram plot more nicely (also in dendextend). Also look at the tanglegram function.